# Save as a blob from download URL

Tags: javascript, typescript, blob

I have a function to get a signed URL from an s3 bucket

```js
GetDownloadURL()
  {
    this.config.configCredentials()

    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const myBucket = 'bucket'
    const bucketKey = 'bucketKey.xlsx'
    const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5 // your expiry time in seconds.

    let url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
      Bucket: myBucket,
      Key: bucketKey,
      Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
    })

    console.log("The URL is " + url)

    return url
  }
```

and added to the function a way to load the url and save it to the user machine by creating a hidden `a` element.

```js
let link = document.createElement('a')
      link.download = 'downloadFileName'
      link.href = url
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      link.click();
```

I was wondering though since I want to add some stuff to the excel file before actually doing the download is there a way to store the download as a Blob so I can work with it first using the signed url?

Comment: like `fetch(url).then( r => r.blob())`?

Comment: something to that effect yes

Comment: @Kaiido would I need to add another then statement or something though to actually access the blob because it seems like that just returns a promise object if im not mistaken

Comment: Yes of course..

Comment: care to elaborate lol I'm terrible with promises

Comment: Well just .then(blob=>doSomethingWithBlob(blob)) or if you prefer you can even use XMLHttpRequest with its xhr.responseType = "blob".